# Are literals and values the same thing?

Tags: javascript

My understanding is that variables point to values, and while the same variable can be reassigned to multiple values, the values themselves are immutable. While Learning JavaScript the concept of "literals" seems to come up often, but I haven't found a clear explanation that differentiates between *literals* and *values*. In fact, one author equates them.

How would you compare literals to values? Please provide simple examples.

To anyone interested, I found [this explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal) very helpful. The way I see it now, literals always result in themselves after evaluation, whereas values can be more complex (e.g. expressions) and can evaluate to something different than themselves.

Comment: Which author equates them? He's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Well, literals are representations of values. But values are not literals.

For example, a numeric literal could be `45`. That's a four character followed by a five character. But when the JavaScript interpreter sees this, it knows to turn it into a numeric value -- a JS `Number` representing the floating-point number `0x4046800000000000` (according to some decimal to IEEE754 binary converter I found online).

A string literal is `"something like this"` (some characters surrounded by quotation marks). An array literal is `[something, like, this]` (comma-separate expressions surrounded by square brackets).

"Literals" are syntactic notions. They are ways of identifying values to the JS interpreter. You could get the same array with `new Array(something, like, this)`, but that's not a literal, because it isn't using the literal syntax.

Object literal: `{foo: bar}`. It would be totally valid to call `true` and `false` "boolean literals," but I don't think I've ever heard anyone actually say that.

---

Above is the answer to your question. Below some supporting information that might make your learning process a little less painful:

> My understanding is that variables point to values, and while the same variable can be reassigned to multiple values, the values themselves are immutable.

"Point to" is sort of a heavy term that has a precise meaning when you're programming, but that doesn't come up often in JavaScript (because you don't have explicit pointers).

There are mutable and immutable values in JavaScript. Strings, for example, are immutable. So are numbers. You can't *change* the string `"foo"`. If I say

```
var x = "foo";
var y = x;
```

There's nothing I can do to `x` that will change the value of `y`. Although internally we know this isn't what's happening, we can pretend that when we assign an immutable type (like a string or a number), it's making a copy of that value each time (it's not actually, because that would be inefficient, but semantically it looks the same to us).

However:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = x;
```

Now both `x` and `y` represent a mutable value, which we can change:

```
x.push(4);
console.log(y); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
y.push(5);
console.log(x); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Both `x` and `y` are names for the same array, and whether we're trying to change `x` or `y`, we're actually changing the same underlying array. You can say that the variables `x` and `y` "point to" the same array, or "hold references to" the same array, or whatever, and you're basically saying the same thing.

Things like numbers and strings can't be changed, so we don't have to worry about this distinction. But arrays and objects are mutable, so we do. Whether or not the variables store pointers to the numbers or strings or actually store the numbers or strings themselves is sort of irrelevant to the programmer, as it behaves as if they store copies of the entire values (but internally the JS engine is going to do whatever it thinks is faster).

Comment: Would it be fair to say that assigning variables to literals, what you see is what you get (WYSIWYG)? The way I understand your post, writing 45 is like telling the interpreter, Map the characters 45 to the mathematical number 45. To the programmer, the character sequence and the mathematical number look exactly the same on screen, but internally the interpreter maps the characters 45 to some kind of binary value it can work with. Would this be an accurate summary?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If JavaScript lacked, say, object literals, you could still get objects by writing `var x = new Object(); x['foo'] = 'bar';`, but you don't get the nice object literal syntax of `var x = {foo: 'bar'};`

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of literal is simply a constant value, such as `1`, or `true`.

A variable is the opposite of a literal; a variable's value can change while a literal's can not.

Answer (score 2):

> You use **literals** to represent values in JavaScript. These are
>   fixed values, not variables, that you `literally` provide in your
>   script.

You can check out this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals).

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" answer is

If the variable's value is a primitive and the literal represents a primitive, you can have `variable === literal`

```
var x = 1;
x === 1;             // true
```

If the variable is non-primitive, `variable !== literal`, even if they are equivalent

```
var x = new Number(1);
x === 1;             // false
x === new Number(1); // false
// or
var a = [1, 2];
a === [1, 2];        // false
```

However, `===` will return `true` if comparing non-primitive variable to non-primitive variable as long as they point to the same place in memory;

```
var b = a;           // `a` as above
a === b;             // true
```

For more information about `===`, look at the MDN page for [**comparison operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and the ES5 specification for the [**The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)

Comment: In your first example, you make a distinction between the _variable's value 1_ and the _literal 1_ you use for comparison. But isn't x's value a literal itself? Obviously, values can be considerably more complex than literals, so would it be accurate to say that literals evaluate to themselves?